# How do I make a variable increment by adding a counter variable to the end inside a while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to get a variable to increment by adding a counter to the end of it.  Here is the code.

```
$counter = 0;
while($results = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $var . ++$counter = $results['row'];
    } // while loop
```

My target outcome...

```
$var1 = result 1
$var2 = result 2
$var3 = result 3
```

It is trying to set $counter = result.

Comment: Your code is invalid, you cannot assign to an expression like `$var . ++$counter`.

Comment: I know.  That is why I'm asking in here.  It obviously didnt work.  If I knew how to do it, it would be pointless to ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a variable variable you can use `{}`:

```
$counter = 0;
while($results = $query->fetch_assoc()){
   ${"var".++$counter} = $results['row'];
} // while loop
```

Comment: wow.  I should have known that.  I just did something similar the other day.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note (For your information only, @KDJ), this works as well with strings: `"{$result['row']} is the result of {$var} at counter {++$counter}";`

Comment: that seemed to make $var an array.  Why is this?