# Variable variables doesn't work as expected and is creating an array

Tags: php, arrays, variable-variables

I'm using this line of code:

```
$var{++$counter} = $results['row'];
```

I've set this up with a goal of creating these variables:

```
$var1 = row 1
$var2 = row 2
$var3 = row 3
```

Why is it created an array for `$var` ? Instead of just defining three variables?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: It states my question below the code and in the title.... Why is it created an array for $var instead of just defining the variables.

Comment: Do it like: `${"var".++$counter} = $results['row'];`

Comment: Because that's not the correct syntax for variable variables. (Which this would also be a poor use case for. What's wrong with using an array? What's the purpose here?)

Comment: Curly braces can be used for array position, just like square brackets. Darn you PHP!

Comment: @Daan And you answered the last question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30504089/3933332 :)?!

Comment: @mario - No reason specifically..Just experimenting.  This was showed me me and wanted to see how it responded and the use of it.

Comment: @Rizier123 - yes he did..haha.

Comment: @Rizier123 Oh wow didn't even notice, edited that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because `{}` can also be used to access arrays as you can read from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> **Note:**
>   **Both square brackets and curly braces** can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above).

Means the following 2 lines are the same:

```
$var{++$counter}
$var[++$counter]
```

What you want is [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which would be this:

```
${"var" . ++$counter} = $results['row'];
```